# How can I update the voice channel when a user enters the guild with JDA

Tags: java, discord-jda

I basically wanted to convert this code to JDA

JavaScript

```js
bot.channels.get(serverStats.totalUserID).setName(`Total Users: ${member.guild.memberCount}`);
```

Java (Error)

```java
public void onGuildJoin(GuildJoinEvent event) {
     event.getGuild().getTextChannelById(573629024102776853L).setName("Total Users:" + event.getGuild().getMembers().size()); //<---- Error
}
```

Comment: What is your question, in English?

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide some information about the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify an entity in JDA you usually have to use the manager. You can acquire an instance of a manager through `getManager()` on almost every entity.

```java
TextChannel channel = guild.getTextChannelById(573629024102776853L);
channel.getManager()
       .setName("Total Users:" + guild.getMemberCache().size())
       .queue(); // this is needed, otherwise the request won't be made to discord
```

If the id for the channel is incorrect it will throw an NPE on `channel.getManager()` because `getTextChannelById` will return null.
I used `getMemberCache()` instead of `getMembers()` because its more efficient for this kind of code. The size is directly available on the cache-view instance and does not require copying the entire cache into a list which is effectively what `getMembers()` does.

Answer (score 2):

To rename a TextChannel you have to use the manager. 
For example this:

```
  event.getGuild().getTextChannelById(573629024102776853L).getManager().setName("Total Users:" + event.getGuild().getMembers().size());
```

Check out [Channel#getManager()](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/blob/master/src/main/java/net/dv8tion/jda/core/managers/ChannelManager.java) for more information.

Comment: The postfix `L` means it is a long literal. The ID is too big for an integer literal and thus needs to be postfixed with `L` otherwise the compiler will say its too large for an integer.